# Same but without loops

Tags: python, loops

So I've got this module called risar. And what it does, it draws. But that's not really of importance. I wrote this code which sets 20 flowers on the background. The code works but it looks horribly awkward to me. I'd like it to look more "fancy" or maybe that less loops would be used. I'm relatively new to python.

```
import risar
import random


def makeFlowers():
    flowers = []
    for i in range(5):
        colors = ["black_flower.svg","blue_flower.svg", "brown_flower.svg", "green_flower.svg","purple_flower.svg"]
        for j in range(4):
            x = random.randint(20, (risar.maxX-20))
            y = random.randint(20, 300)
            flower = risar.picture(x, y, colors[i])
            flowers.append(flower)
    return flowers

flowers = makeFlowers()
```

Comment: Factor out `colors`, since it's remaining constant.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review.  Should be on the code review stackexchange site (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't know that existed. Thanks for letting me know, appreciate it and will definitely use it! xD

Comment: I'd say it's on topic: he's asking how to write code more pythonically.   The itertools library helps encapsulate loops like the one you have here.  And don't forget my map. See my explicit-loop-free rewrite at http://pastie.org/8643352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters, you're setting the `color` variable to the same list, five times, so you can remove that from the loop:

```
# Just set `colors` once
colors = ["black_flower.svg","blue_flower.svg", "brown_flower.svg","green_flower.svg","purple_flower.svg"]
for i in range(5): 
    # Do stuff
```

Second, you're using two loops for no reason at all. Hint: if you're not using `j` for anything, it might not deserve its own loop.

Instead, pull the code that you want to repeat together, and then repeat it that many times. In this case, you want to repeat your block of code twenty times, but you're using nested loops just to make sure you rotate through the colors. Instead, notice that the number of flowers you're drawing is divisible by the length of your color list, and refactor the whole thing into a single loop:

```
for i in range(20):
    x = random.randint(20, (risar.maxX-20))
    y = random.randint(20, 300)
    flower = risar.picture(x, y, colors[i//4]) # 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, etc...
    flowers.append(flower)
```

Comment: Much better way, i would just replace the range for the xrange function

Comment: @rekiem87 The gains from `xrange` vs `range` in a 20-item loop are extremely minimal. Also, the OP didn't specify a Python version, and `range` in Python3 works like `xrange` did in Python 2 (and `xrange` no longer exists!)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
colors = ["black_flower.svg","blue_flower.svg", "brown_flower.svg", "green_flower.svg","purple_flower.svg"]
for color in colors:
    //You can do your second for here, no need to redeclare colors in each for, and color will be taking each value of the array
```

And just one more thing, you better use

```
xrange(limit)
```

The difference is that xrange is more efficient since doesn't create a list of numbers, just a sequence generator, this is very important in heavy memory programs, like a painting one